# I want to save different date format tha saved in yii2 datepicker

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii2

I am using yii2 datepicker in my project.
I want to show selected date as dd/mm/YYYY but want to save date in model as YYYY-mm-dd.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can format datepicker in Controller,and then render the view.

**Controller:**

```
$model->birth_date=Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->birth_date, "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Then Store like this:

```
$model->birth_date=Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->birth_date, "yyyy-mm-dd");
```